# Скрыть скроллбары в консольном приложении c#

Tags: c#, консоль

Нужно скрыть скроллбары в консоли, вариант с уменьшением размер буфера консоли не подходит, т.к. необходимо, чтоб размер буфера превышал размер окна консоли.

В последний раз делал так:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, bool bShow);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       ShowScrollBar(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_BOTH, false);
    }
```

Но такая конструкция не работает, пожалуйста, подскажите, возможно ли это сделать в принципе и как, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что означает «не работает»?

Comment: Скроллбар не скрывается

Comment: А если то же вызвать из нативного процесса? И да, вы проверили код ошибки? Чему равен MainWindowHandle?

Answer (score 1):

Можно задавать размер буфера окна так, чтобы он был равен размеру окна, тогда скролл пропадет. Это необходимо делать по событию изменения размера окна, но к сожалению такое событие нельзя перехватить насколько я знаю. Поэтому есть вот такой вариант - создать поток и в нем проверять изменился ли размер окна и выставлять размер буфера. Тестировал на Windows 10, скролл изредка появляется на доли секунды при растягивании окна:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace DeleteMeConsole
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private enum ScrollBarDirection
        {
            SB_HORZ = 0,
            SB_VERT = 1,
            SB_CTL = 2,
            SB_BOTH = 3
        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, bool bShow);

        private static bool _checkWndSize;

        private struct WndSize
        {
            public int CurrentHeight;
            public int CurrentWidth;
        }

        private static WndSize _wndSize;

        private static void Main()
        {
            OnWndResize();
            _checkWndSize = true;
            var t = new Thread(OnWndResize);
            t.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
            _checkWndSize = false;
            t.Join();
        }
        private static void OnWndResize()
        {
            while (_checkWndSize)
            {
                if (_wndSize.CurrentWidth != Console.WindowWidth || _wndSize.CurrentHeight != Console.WindowHeight)
                {
                    _wndSize.CurrentWidth = Console.WindowWidth;
                    _wndSize.CurrentHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
                    Console.SetWindowSize(_wndSize.CurrentWidth, _wndSize.CurrentHeight);
                    Console.SetBufferSize(_wndSize.CurrentWidth, _wndSize.CurrentHeight);

                   //ShowScrollBar(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle,       (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_BOTH, false); -- this will work either
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

А также в цикле потока можно использовать `ShowScrollBar(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_BOTH, false);`, но в таком случае скролл появляется чаще.